# How to convert input image to 3D image format

Tags: c, image-processing, matrix, rotation

I am trying to write image rotation code in C.

```
 int width, height, channels;
 unsigned char *img = stbi_load("butterfly.jpg", &width, &height, &channels, 0);
```

I am reading the image as seen. I want to convert these image data to 3D (row, column, channel) array format to be able to do this line:

```
if (Xprime >= 1 && Yprime >= 1 && Xprime <= height && Yprime <= width)
            {
                pixel = img[Xprime][Yprime];
        }
        returnedOutImage[i][j] = pixel;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast it to VLA.
I assume that pixels are ordered by y, next by x, finally by the channel.

```
unsigned char (*img3d)[width][channels] = (void*)img;
```

Now you can access it by `img3[y][x][c]`.

There is a question if such a cast violates strict aliasing rules.